# How to fix an image perfectly to a modal like in Facebook?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When we click an image on Facebook it opens in a modal and perfectly fits on it How it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Real solution I found was set the image to

```
Max-width:100%; 
Max-height:100%; 
Margin :auto;
```

and set the div to exact size you want

```
width:500px;
height:400px;
margin:auto;
overflow:hidden;
```

The image will perfectly fit and adjust, According to the size.

Answer (score 1):

Check your image size first.
if your image very height, set image height = 100%
but if your image width is too long, set image width = 100%

Comment: If the Hight is too long it goes out of the modal even if it is set to 100%

Comment: Thank. I fixed it now.